# Globalize selectors in redux toolkit with correct typing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In my slice I create simple local selectors, e.g.:

```
const getSomething = (state: TreeState) => simpleOperations(state.something)
```

which for example returns a `number`.

Since they are functions, I easily use them in the reducers too, to avoid code repetitions.

Now I'd like to export them to be used elsewhere in components.
I might simply do:

```
const something = useSelector(state => getSomething(state.tree))
```

(assuming that state is of type `RootState`, has a sub state `tree` of type `TreeState`)

But it would be a lot cleaner writing as a global state:

```
const something = useSelector(getSomething)
```

So I would like to let `getSomething` be private in the slice file, and then create an util function `globalizeSelectors` which returns an object with all functions wrapped to be global selectors.

That function is easy, but I'm messing up with types: I expect that since the local selector has signature `(state: TreeState) => number` the corresponding global selector should have signature `(state: RootState) => number` with the same returning type.

So far I wrote this:

```
const getSomething = (state: TreeState) => simpleOperations(state.something)

function globalizeSelectors<T extends {}>(subStateSelector: (state: RootState) => T, selectors: { [key: string]: (subState: T) => any }) {
    const globalized: { [key: keyof typeof selectors]: (state: RootState) => any } = {}
    for (let selector in selectors)
        globalized[selector] = (state: RootState) => selectors[selector](subStateSelector(state))

    return globalized
}

export const treeSelectors = globalizeSelectors<TreeState>(state => state.tree, {getSomething})
```

Example usage in component:

```
const something = useSelector(treeSelectors.getSomething)
```

Caveats: typescript should understand that:

- `treeSelectors` has a property `getSomething`
- `getSomething` property is a function with signature `(state: RootState) => number`
- `something` is a `number`
- everything is dynamic so that I can use any number of local selectors in `globalizeSelectors` with any kind of return types

However this is not working, typescript does not infer anything.

How would you do that?

The `globalizeSelectors` is just an idea, it can be entirely rewritten if you have ideas.